# Related Rates: Find Dx/Dt when xy=-3, dy/dt=2, and x=-4

Tags: calculus

Suppose xy=-3 and dy/dt=2. Find dx/dt when x=-4

Please be very specific, and explain the steps. I am new to implicit differentiation. I know that y=3/4 from substituting xy=3 with x=-4, but I do not understand how to get dy/dx from that, or what to do from there.

Comment: Apply the product rule to $xy = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $xy=-3$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=2$.  Differentiating the former equation implicitly yields $$x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}=0.$$
The left side is an application of the product rule (taking the derivative of $y$ with respect to $t$ and multiplying by $x$, then summing this with the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$ and multiplying by $y$), which is taught in any elementary calculus course, and the right side is the result of differentiating a constant (taking the derivative of $-3$ with respect to $t$ is $0$).  Now, rearranging this equation for $\frac{dx}{dt}$, we find $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dt}.$$
It follows from the given information that first, as you said, $(xy)|_{x=-4}=-4y=-3 \implies y=\frac{3}{4}$. So, the point of interest is $(-4,\frac{3}{4})$.  Second, evaluating the derivative here gives $$\frac{dx}{dt}\biggr|_{(-4,\frac{3}{4})}=\frac{32}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you! It makes so much more sense!

Comment: @Natalie: I actually answered your other question as well. If it was helpful, you can upvote and/or accept the answers.  No problem whatsoever! Let me know if I can help you with understanding anything else.

Comment: Need to go do that :) New to the site, sorry!Actually, it says it requires 15 reputation... and I don't have that.

Comment: No problem, again! You can upvote with the arrow next to the question and accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark that turns green when you hover on it - right below arrow to up/downvote. @Natalie

Comment: Oh ok, you can get reputation by commenting on questions and answering questions, and even by asking questions if people upvote it - you only need one more reputation point, you have 14 currently. @Natalie

Comment: I'll be asking quite a few questions tonight, considering I have such a hard time with Related Rates. I will upvote when I get that last point!